# EventToCommandBehavior: send event args as CommandParameter

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, command, eventtocommand

I use EventToCommandBehavior provided by the Xamarin team from https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior.
I need it to manipulate Xamarin.Forms.Map control events only by the view model. Case: handle click event, then get point's location...

```
        <gmap:Map x:Name="map">
          <gmap:Map.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
              EventName="MapClicked"
              Command="{Binding ClickMapCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{???}"/>
          </gmap:Map.Behaviors>
        </gmap:Map>
```

Everything works, but I don't know how to pass Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.MapClickedEventArgs's Point property as a command parameter. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved. Command's parameter sends automatically. All you need is just to remember to add object arg to your Action