# Xamarin Forms: How to send object and event through to ViewModel on ImageButton Clicked using Commands

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

I've created a `CustomElementTagger` class which allows me to `set` and `get` custom set tags on view elements. I need this because I want to have a single `command` that gets executed but has different behavior on the corresponding tag on the element. In the `ViewModel` I want to receive the tag and work with it accordingly but the `Command` never executes. I've also tried it as an `Object` but the object never comes back as I need it and when I try to cast the `Object` to the `ImageButton` I get an error that I cannot cast this `Object`.

I've looked up youtube videos by [JamesMontemagno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mpe_1okwxk&t=553s&ab_channel=JamesMontemagno) but everything I look at that is using `EventToCommandBehaviour` are `ListViews` with `EventName = "ItemSelected"`.

Also viewed a number of articles and neither of those helped me to understand how to make this work.

All I want is to get my `ImageButton` sender.
Many Thanks in advance.

**CustomElementTagger: Class**

```
public class CustomElementTagger
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TagProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Tag", typeof(object), typeof(CustomElementTagger), null);

    public static string GetTag(BindableObject bindable)
    {
        return (string)bindable.GetValue(TagProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTag(BindableObject bindable, string value)
    {
        bindable.SetValue(TagProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ImageButton WidthRequest="200"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                tagger:CustomElementTagger.Tag="1">
    <ImageButton.Behaviors>
        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Clicked"
                                    Command="{Binding KeyboardTapCommand}" />
    </ImageButton.Behaviors>
</ImageButton>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class SpellViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand NextPageCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand PreviousPageCommand { get; private set; }
    public ICommand KeyboardTapCommand { get; private set; }

    public SpellViewModel()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
        InitializeCommands();
    }

    void InitializeCommands()
    {
        NextPageCommand = Navigation.NextPage(nameof(CopyWhatIDoPage));
        PreviousPageCommand = Navigation.PreviousPage();
        KeyboardTapCommand = new Command<ImageButton>(ReadVirtualKeyboardTap);
    }

    void ReadVirtualKeyboardTap(ImageButton btn) //This never gets executed...
    {
        var tag = CustomElementTagger.GetTag(btn);
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re not passing in any CommandParameter

Comment: @Jason please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622710/eventtocommandbehavior-send-event-args-as-commandparameter#:~:text=Solved.%20Command%27s%20parameter%20sends%20automatically.%20All%20you%20need%20is%20just%20to%20remember%20to%20add%20object%20arg%20to%20your%20Action)

Comment: `ImageButton` has a `Command` property, why don't you bind the KeyboardTapCommand to this property directly?

Comment: @PharazFadaei because I need to get the `object sender`. This way I can cast the entire object into `ImageButton` and send it to the `GetTag` method. Without the `object sender` that `CustomElementTagger` is useless. Unless there is a way to get the object by just binding the `Command` to `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how `EventToCommandBehavior` works under the hood. But I argue your approach here, is against MVVM. Generally, the view models should be unaware of the details of the view. Here the `ImageButton` is a UI element hence a view detail, which your view model should not care about. You can use `CommandParameter` to achieve what you want. Usually, using command parameters, you can have a single general command that can act differently based on the parameter which in your case is the tag you are assigning.

View:

```xml
<ImageButton WidthRequest="200"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                CommandParameter="1"
                Command="{Binding KeyboardTapCommand}" />
```

View Model:

```cs
KeyboardTapCommand = new Command<string>(ReadVirtualKeyboardTap);


void ReadVirtualKeyboardTap(string tag)
{   
}
```

This way, the tag (as a command parameter) will be directly sent to your `ReadVirtualKeyboardTap` method. And you can decide what to do based on that.

Comment: Thank you for the nice argument provided with the answer. I fully understood what you meant and I completely forgot that `CommandParameters` exist. Thanks